# Read xml file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a file localy with the following structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<foxydata>
<store_version>2.0</store_version>
<result>ERROR</result>
<messages>
<context>2008</context>
<message>Transaction Not Found (transaction_id:25)</message>
</messages>
</foxydata>
```

I want to read that file and return it to the browser, so my code is like:

```
options = 
    encoding = 'UTF8'

fs.readFileSync(filepathXML, options, (err, data) ->
  throw err  if err
  return data
)
```

I can read the file but the result on the browser is like:

```
2.0SUCCESSTransaction Found
```

Any idea what is causing the problem or how can I read a xml file, should I define something else on readFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`readFileSync`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) there is no third option. Maybe do you mean [`readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback)?

1.

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    console.log(fs.readFileSync('./test.xml', {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
```

2.

```
    var fs   = require('fs');
    var http = require('http');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
      res.end(fs.readFileSync('./test.xml', {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
    }).listen(8811);
```

3.

```
    var express = require('express'),
        app     = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
      res.send(fs.readFileSync('./test.xml', {encoding: 'utf-8'}))
    })

    app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
fs = require('fs');
var parser = require('xml2json');

fs.readFile( './data.xml', function(err, data) {
    var json = parser.toJson(data);
    console.log("to json ->", json);
 });
```